# How to configure ulimit with supervisord (to start varnish)

Tags: varnish, ulimit, supervisord

I am migrating a server configuration to supervisord (from init.d files).

There are a few instances of varish running. I remember when I started using varnish I had ulimit problems so there is the following lines in the init.d/varnish scripts

ulimit -n ${NFILES:-131072}
ulimit -l ${MEMLOCK:-82000}

I am configuring supervisord to run the /usr/sbin/varnishd program with arguments.

How do you configure the ulimit settings via supervisord? Do I just wrap the varnishd program in a script?

Comment: BTW currently I am using this script (/usr/local/bin/varnishd)

    #! /bin/sh
    ulimit -n ${NFILES:-131072} 
    ulimit -l ${MEMLOCK:-82000} 
    exec /usr/sbin/varnishd $@

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to go this route it would be preferred to set the ulimit at a system level (see [limits.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf)).  But varnish performs best with a malloc backend rather than a file backend, so if you have the memory resources, this would solve your ulimit problem and improve your performance.  The [documentation is here](https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/Tuning.html#storage-backends), but basically you have something like "-s malloc,1G" in your /etc/default/varnish:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
         -T localhost:1234 \
         -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
         -s malloc,1G"
```